# Remove multidimension array elements which are bigger than X

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this;

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [selling] => 4.0107
            [update_date] => 1522271815
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [selling] => 4.0124
            [update_date] => 1522271876
        )
```

I want to print only selling elements which elements update_date bigger than 1522271876

I can get only selling elements with this `$datay1 = array_column($results, 'selling');` 
but how can i get only SELLING elements update_date bigger than 1522271876 ?

Thanks

EDIT:
I used these codes

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://.com/api/v1/currencies/USD/daily'); 
$contents = utf8_encode($contents); 
$results = json_decode($contents, true); 

$filtered_array = array_filter($results, function($obj){
    if (isset($obj->update_date)) {
        if ($obj->update_date > 1522271876) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
print '<pre>';
print_r($filtered_array);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: @Dave It give this Array ( [0] => 4.0107 [1] => 4.0124 [2] => 4.0125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try something like this with [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function. I've created the whole array of object for you and applied `array_filter()` with the `update_date > 1522271876` condition.

```
<?php
$array = [];
$obj1 = new stdClass;
$obj1->selling = 4.0107;
$obj1->update_date = 1522271815;

$obj2 = new stdClass;
$obj2->selling = 4.0124;
$obj2->update_date = 1522271876;

$obj3 = new stdClass;
$obj3->selling = 4.0129;
$obj3->update_date = 1522271980;
$array = [$obj1,$obj2,$obj3];
print_r($array);
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function($obj){
    if (isset($obj->update_date)) {
        if ($obj->update_date > 1522271876) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
print '<pre>';
print_r($filtered_array);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**INITIAL ARRAY OF OBJECT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [selling] => 4.0107
            [update_date] => 1522271815
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [selling] => 4.0124
            [update_date] => 1522271876
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [selling] => 4.0129
            [update_date] => 1522271980
        )

)
```

**OUTPUT AFTER FILTER:**

```
Array
(
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [selling] => 4.0129
            [update_date] => 1522271980
        )

)
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/980839

**EDIT**: It is just multidimensional array i.e **array of array** but on your question you put **array of object**,  So now the code will be like this as I seen your API response. So dont use **->** , instead use **[ ]**

$contents=file_get_contents('https://doviz.com/ap
    i/v1/curren
    cies/USD/daily'); 
    $results = json_decode($contents, true);

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($results, 
function($arr){
if (isset($arr['update_date'])) {
    if ($arr['update_date'] > 1522271876)
     return  true;
}
     return false;
});

print '<pre>';
print_r($filtered_array);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: @can check my edited answer now. and let me know whether it is working now or not for you

Comment: It show empty array so not worked. I also editted my codes on my question. you can see my codes

Comment: See the edit again. On your initial question you put array of object but api response is array of array i.e multidimensional array. Try my edit again

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_filter to apply a callback that filters down your array.

You can look at the docs here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php